# How to send a 'fake' command to Appium

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I'm trying to test my android application with appium and I'm looking for a solution to the following issue:
In my application I have a section that takes time (for image processing) and it sometimes can take one minute, two minute or even more depends on the image size, quality.

In my test case I'm trying to wait for lets say 30 seconds and then I'm checking if the image processing is done.

The problem is if I'm waiting too long, I got the next message:
info: [debug] Didn't get a new command in 60 secs, shutting down...

I don't want to set a 'newCommandTimeout' cause I want to cut the test time and I want to test check if its done every short period.
In addition, I can't use the wait for element or something like that of appium API because I'm using a third party library which tells me when the image processing is done.

My questions is, there is any way to send a 'fake' command to appium so every 30 seconds that my thread is back to work and if I see that the image processing is not done I'll send a fake command and then go back to sleep for 30 seconds without any worry that the appium server will be shut down due to timeout?

Comment: I think long wait is only solution...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the comment here:

In order to solve this issue I use the WebDriverWait with a custom ExpectedCondition and it looks like:

```
new WebDriverWait(mDriver, 30)           // 30 is for the time out
    .withMessage("You can set any custom error message")
    .until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
          @Override
          public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                //This function will be called repeatedly until 
                //the return value will be true 
          }

    });
```

You can see other implementations of WebDriverWait and actually I think it works with any Object instead of Boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are using for wait command. Use this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
```

This will wait until it finds the element on screen.